# Need to shuffle a linked list of a deck of cards, getting an infinite loop

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing code for a class and I need to shuffle a desk of linked list of cards in C++. I am basically having the code swap two cards position many times in order to randomize their order. However, I'm having a lot of trouble getting the pointers right and I end up in an infinite loop of a card pointing to itself when I try to print it out. I was wondering if anybody can see anything wrong.

```
void deck::shuffle() //shuffles deck linked list of 52 card objects
{
    node<card> *curr1 = new node<card>;
    node<card> *curr2 = new node<card>;
    node<card> *prev1 = new node<card>;
    node<card> *prev2 = new node<card>;
    node<card> temp1;
    node<card> temp2;
    randomNumber rand;
    int random1, random2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        curr1 = front;
        curr2 = front;
        prev1 = NULL;
        prev2 = NULL;
        random1 = rand.random(51);
        random2 = rand.random(52 - random1) + random1;
        while (random1 == random2)
            random2 = rand.random(52 - random1) + random1;

        for (int j = 0; j < random1; j++)
        {
            prev1 = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < random2; k++)
        {
            prev2 = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }

        temp1 = *curr1;
        temp1.next = curr1->next;

        if (curr1->next == curr2)
        {
            curr1->next = curr2->next;
            curr2->next = curr1;
        }

        else
        {
            curr1->next = curr2->next;
            curr2->next = temp1.next;
        }

        if (prev2 == NULL)
            front = curr1;
        else
            prev2->next = curr1;

        if (prev1 == NULL)
            front = curr2;
        else
            prev1->next = curr2;

    }
}
```

Comment: First I think you need to review your algorithum, have you seen the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithum.

Comment: Also see [Securing a Shuffle Algorithm](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/62440) and [Secure shuffles and the rand() function](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/68044) on Security SE.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you pseudo code because I don't like writing people's homeworks. It shouldn't be difficult to translate to code though.

```
srand(time(NULL)); //seeds the random number generator
ran1 = rand() % NUM_ITEMS_IN_LIST; //otherwise you can get 9989798690
ran2 = rand() % ...

Node* firstNode = head;
for (int i=1 i <= ran1; i++)
{
   firstNode = firstNode->next;
}

//same for second node

swap(firstNode, secondNode);
```

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is *not* a multiple of `NUM_ITEMS_IN_LIST`, then there's a small bias in your algorithm due to the modular reduction. Suppose you had a generator that returns 0,1,2 or 3; and suppose you needed values mod 2. Then 1 is going to show up twice as often as 0 and 2 because `1 mod 2` and `3 mod 2` each result in 1.

Comment: Sure. But why over kill it? It's homework after all.

Comment: What i am not getting is that ,you are generating two random numbers what for the others ? but it doesn't mean exactly shuffle, even you give the algorithm psudo code to help for homework, needs more information for the person who will implement that...

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, there are lots of things that are wrong with your code:

- you initialize `curr1`, `curr2`, `prev1` and `prev2` by calling `new`, but then you directly assign them (meaning that you have a memory leak in addition to the useless initialization)
- `random1` is an integer between 0 and 51 (if `rand.random()` does what I assume it does), which means that `rand.random(52 - random1) + random1` goes from 0 to 52. I'm assuming that you are trying to get `random1` and `random2` between 0 and 51, with `random1 < random2`, so this is not what you want: try `random1 = rand.random(50);` and  `random2 = rand.random(50 - random1) + random1 + 1;` (that will also allow you to skip the `while`).
- `temp1.next = curr1->next;` is useless after `temp1 = *curr1;` (also, you don't really need `temp1` but only an address to store `curr1->next`, and you never use `temp2`)

That being said, to get you out of your trouble:

- It seems to me that the only way you can enter an infinite loop is if `while (random1 == random2)` stays true, and it also seems that a card can only point to itself after `curr1->next = curr2->next;` with `curr2->next == curr1`. Since those things are not supposed to happen, I would check if the problem comes from `rand.random()` if I were you.
- If you really want to understand what's going on, printing things out won't be enough help. The usual thing to do is to use a debugger: set a breakpoint and execute the program instruction by instruction to see what's really happening (it also allows you to look at the values of the variables). If you use an IDE, they usually include a debugger and make the use of breakpoint very easy (you can find plenty information on how to do that by googling "breakpoint" and the name of your IDE).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ended up getting it working. I think the condition of dealing with the Front card was what was giving me trouble, so I ended up shuffling the cards 2-52 and then randomly shuffling the front card separately at the end to keep it simple.